# Asserting two statements are true at the same time in Selenium Unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, python-unittest

I have been trying to assert that two textbox elements contain two specific values for a successful test.

Textbox 1: 100
Textbox 2: 0

I have tried the following code:

```
def test_example(self):

    self.set_textbox1('100')
    self.set_textbox2('0')

    tb1 = self.find_by_id('textbox1')
    tb2 = self.find_by_id('textbox2') 

    self.assertEquals((tb1.get_attribute('value'), 100) and (tb2.get_attribute('value'), 0))
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_textboxes.py", line 48, in test_textbox
self.assertEquals((tb1.get_attribute('value'), 100) and (tb2.get_attribute('value'), 0))
TypeError: assertEqual() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: create a second assertion line, or a loop

Comment: @AriGold I thought it was bad practice to have multiple assertions within one test case?

Comment: Note: assertEquals is a deprecated alias, use assertEqual instead https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may solve your issue:

**Concatenating the 2 strings:**

```
self.assertEqual(tb1.get_attribute('value') + tb2.get_attribute('value'), '1000')
```

Or:

```
self.assertEqual(''.join([tb1.get_attribute('value'), tb2.get_attribute('value')]), '1000')
```

**Using tuples:**

```
self.assertEqual((tb1.get_attribute('value'), tb2.get_attribute('value')), (100, 0))
```

Comment: Take a look at the edit for an example using `.join()`

Answer (score 1):

For me is the readability one of the most important points on unit testing, i would prefer to have multi lines assertion for each case.
You can keep your workflow but using [assertEqual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases) and add something like that

```
self.assertEqual((tb1.get_attribute('value'),tb2.get_attribute('value'),(100,0))
```

the AssertionError would be, lets say the first value query is 99:

```
AssertionError: (99,0) != (100,0)
```